# Converting specfic json data to txt file in Python

Tags: python, json, nlp, txt

So I currently have a JSON file in the format like this

```
{"doc": "small-grains-report_2019.pdf", "url": "https://www.uidaho.edu/-/media/UIdaho-Responsive/Files/Extension/topic/cereals/scse/2019/small-grains-report_2019.pdf", "chunk": "41", "sentences": {"Overall yield was slightly below average (Table 49) and similar to ABI Growler, with average or better test weight and plumps.": {"entity 1": {"start": 8, "end": 13, "label": "TRAT"}, "entity 2": {"start": 67, "end": 78, "label": "CVAR"}, "entity 3": {"start": 103, "end": 114, "label": "TRAT"}}
```

I wanted to extract the data in the form of

```
Overall yield was slightly below average (Table 49) and similar to ABI Growler, with average or better test weight and pl, TRAT: Yield, CVAR: ABI Growler, TRAT: test weight and plumps
```

Then write to a txt file. Is there any way possible to do that with python? It would mean a lot to me struggling at my first job

Comment: So what code have you tried to perform this? Did you know that python has a built-in `json` module?

Comment: This library is the one you want, specifically the `json.loads()` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html Depending on your familiarity with Python, you might also want to look into string formatting: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So I did use [json.load and pandas](https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/blob/main/jsontotxt.py) to extract the values but it still left out the irrelevant data [like this](https://github.com/Da-vid21/Outputs/blob/main/Test.txt) would going from json to csv then csv to txt be better?